# "Hedgerow Parson" Image

Tags: meaning

This is an excerpt from the article An Honest Man by Peter Lyon in the American Heritage magazine(Feb, 1959).

> Daniel Drew (1797-1879) was a short, chunky man with a face as seamed and wrinkled as a prune; he walked with a stealthy tread, like a cat; his attire was downright dowdy; he affected the bland, who-me? air of a **hedgerow parson**. Yet for a quarter-century this man was one of the most justly feared in the financial circles of nineteenth-century America.

I am not really sure what this 'hedgerow parson' image is trying to convey? Could it refer to some dull and humorless figure?

Comment: I'm also curious to know although I guess ["hedgerow"](https://www.google.com/search?q=hedgerows+countryside&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLiInij7jUAhWEnRoKHYUtBHoQ_AUIBigB&biw=1440&bih=664) suggests conformity, and rigidity. Could you please say the name of the source, and if you tried looking up the term hedgerow, why that didn't help you.

Comment: The phrase also appears in a book published in Britain in 1898 ([*Municipal Parks, Gardens, and Open Spaces of London*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cFVEBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA527&lpg=PA527&dq=hedgerow+parson&source=bl&ots=yHol8oqhIM&sig=RhnrmsI-bH0e7IBd-sxqsA_DFyY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY5Ofjj7jUAhXMblAKHSEhCjUQ6AEIPDAE))

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have just edited my post and provided the source and my thought.

Comment: The online edition of *American Heritage* gives the article the title [*By of Contrast: "Uncle Dan" Drew*](http://www.americanheritage.com/content/way-contrast-%E2%80%9Cuncle-dan%E2%80%9D-drew)

Comment: He argued for social equality and his radical views brought him into conflict with the Church. He gave open-air sermons on village greens and other public spaces, hence his description as a **hedgerow priest**… [source](http://www.redsaundersphoto.eu/1380.html)

Answer (score 3):

Whilst dictionaries seem to be largely silent on the subject of 'Hedgerow Parsons', they do acknowledge '**Hedge Priests**' and '**Hedge Parsons**'.

**Hedge** itself as an adjective is defined in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85371#eid1945913) as

> a. Born, brought up, habitually sleeping, sheltering, or plying their
>   trade under hedges, or by the road-side (and hence used generally as
>   an attribute expressing contempt), as **hedge-bantling, hedge-brat,
>   hedge-chaplain, hedge-curate, hedge-doctor, hedge-lawyer,
>   hedge-parson, hedge-player, hedge-poet, hedge-wench, hedge-whore**, etc.
>   Also hedge-priest n.

And [**Hedge-priest**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85389#eid1950971) is defined there as:

> An illiterate or uneducated priest of inferior status. (contemptuous.)

There is a reference in [The Peacock Lincolnshire word books: 1884-1920](https://books.google.com/books?id=xa9ZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22hedgerow%20parson%22&dq=%22hedgerow%20parson%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNlLK8lLjUAhUsIsAKHZDNBaAQ6AEIOjAE)

> **hedgerow parson** A local preacher
>   In the Lincolnshire context I would take Local preacher to refer to a Methodist Lay preacher and to be a contemptuous reference to their non-conformism and in particular to Primitive Methodism which favoured outdoor services.

This suggest that there are nuances of definition; a literal one where it refer to someone who preaches outdoors and a figurative one where a person is disdained as being of low status and outside of some set of societal norms.

Comment: If you want, you can also cite this snippet from [Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=cXq7AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=%22hedgerow+priest%22&source=bl&ots=PWVOESWmVg&sig=b9cULMRnIsDN9HO19NH3qzOK6Ms&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hedgerow%20priest%22&f=false)

Comment: How does   "the  bland,  who-me? air" fit in here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my copy of [Brewer's](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Brewers-Dictionary-Phrase-Fable-18th/dp/0550104119) to hand, but it's [quoted online in a discussion about the very similar "hedge-priest"](https://shaksper.net/archive/1999/153-march/8020-re-hedge-priest):

> My old edition of Brewer's gives the following entry for hedge priest:
>   "A poor or vagabond parson.  The use of hedge for vagabond, or very
>   inferior, is common; as hedge-mustard, hedge-writer (a Grubb Street
>   author), hedge-marriage (a clandestine one), etc.  Shakespeare uses the
>   phrase, 'hedge-born swain' as the opposite of 'gentle blood.' (1 Henry
>   VI., iv.  1)."

which appears in *Love's Labour's Lost*:

> LLL V.ii.538
>
> BEROWNE
>
> The pedant, the braggart, the hedge-priest, the
>   hedge-priest
>
> fool, and the boy.
>
> Abate throw at novum, and the whole world again
>
> Cannot pick out five such, take each one in his vein.

Comment: And what connection does this have with  "the  bland,  who-me? air" of such a person?

Comment: @Clare that's a good question.  A definition is easy compared to understand an author's intent.

Comment: I believe Sir Oliver Martext in *As You Like It* 3.3 is also commonly termed a hedge-priest in *Dramatis Personae* though not in the actual play-text.

Comment: @BrianDonovan any full text I can find online describes Martext as "a vicar" or "a country vicar", but some commentaries use the phrase "hedge-parson" for him

Answer (score 0):

Well, per the author, the hedgerow parson is known for, or can at least have, "the bland, who-me? air." And he wears dowdy/unfashionable clothes. This means something of an unpretentious, unassuming, self-deprecating person. Whether the author is using *hedgerow parson* to mean simply *local parson*, *vagabond parson*, and/or *contemptuous parson* is unknown at this pount.

[*Greens dictionary of slang*](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/cumteea#gyeanpq) has an entry for *hedge-priest/hedge parson*: "a priest, or a beggar who poses as such, who works in rural areas, ministering to other beggars and the local peasantry; the implication is that such clergy were not true priests.

But it is not clear whether the UK usage of *hedge parson* is the same as that of the 1959 US *hedgerow parson.*

But the words dowdy and "the bland, who-me? air", even if the latter is "affected" by the subject of the essay, are important descriptors.

I realise this "answer" is no more conclusive than the others, and I would be glad to combine mine with an existing answer.

Comment: His persona belies his competence.